# windows batch sticking to the directory where the batch file is run

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am facing a strange problem
I have a batch file say batch1.bat
inside this batch file, I call a perl script say perl1.pl
then inside this perl1.pl, I call another batch file say batch2.bat

Now I call batch1.bat from locatoin say : F:\mydir\tests\scripts
Then it ends up calling batch2.bat, at the end of batch2 completion when I change directory to F:\mydir\tests using cd ..
the DOS window shows it changed the directory, but when I issue the command "dir" it gives me list of files in F:\mydir\tests\scripts and not in F:\mydir\tests
What is the reason? Thanks for help.

Comment: Holy...Whoever is downing this... Not sure if they belong here....

Comment: I managed to move all my logic into a single batch file, so now only batch1.bat -> perl.pl -> back to batch1.bat -> finish...The other route batch1.bat -> perl.pl -> batch2.bat doesn't seem to work as far as cd'ing is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

When writing .bat files `echo %~dp0` is used to reference the directory the .bat file is placed in.

For example:

```
@echo off
call %~dp0\example.bat
```

will call the file named example.bat that is in the same directory as the .bat file you are initially running.

To see what this piece of code really means you can run the following code in a .bat file:

```
@echo off
echo %~dp0
@pause
```

For me, the outcome printed in the console is: C:\Users\Brad\Desktop.

Hopefully this was able to help you achieve your goal. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you call a batch file from inside another program (in this case `perl.exe`), it creates a completely new instance of `cmd.exe` to run the new batch file.  You can set variables, change directory, etc in that new instance, but it has no effect on the original one.  When the new cmd.exe exits, any changes are lost and you resume running in the old instance.

Note that this doesn't happen if you call batch2 directly from batch1, because they use the same instance of cmd.exe.  The problem is that another program is in between.

If you need batch1 to change directory, then batch1 needs to `cd` once batch2 is finished.

Comment: I tried cd F:\mydir\tests at the end of batch1.bat, it still stays at F:\mydir\tests\scripts

Comment: How do you launch batch1.bat?

Comment: F:\mydir\tests\scripts\batch1.bat

Comment: Specifically, what environment are you in?  Explorer, or a command prompt?  If the latter, how are you launching the command prompt? Is that the exact command line you're typing in the command prompt? What OS are you running?  Your observations do not agree with my testing in cmd.exe on Windows 8.1.

Comment: I have a DOS window with F:\mydir\tests   then I cd to "scripts". so my prompt is now F:\mydir\tests\scripts. Then I run batch1.bat, at the end of the batch1, if I change dir using cd .. , the prompt changes to F:\mydir\tests. No problem so far. Now when I do "dir" it lists the files in F:\mydir\tests\scripts

Comment: I got nothing.  Your scripts directory is haunted.